# Nodejs reading file ENAMETOOLONG

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to use `const config = fs.readFileSync(configFilePath,'utf8');`

But It actually returned me an error that is mentioned below:

```
fs.js:663
  return binding.open(pathModule.toNamespacedPath(path),
                 ^

Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, open '/Users/akshaysood/Blockchain/fabricSDK/dist/name: "Network"
version: "1.0"
```

The file that I am trying to read is available at https://hastebin.com/ubaqakixit.http

I am new to `node.js`. If anyone knows this error please let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The node sdk accepts Yaml file path as input, instead of accepts Yaml file content. So it should be

```
const path = require('path');
const config= path.resolve(configFilePath);
```

to go on